# retrieving all results in RavenDB

Tags: f#, ravendb, iqueryable

I thought I could force to retrieve all results through multiple page and skip, using the statistics function

```
   type Linq.IRavenQueryable<'T>
    with member q.getAll() =  let mutable stat = Linq.RavenQueryStatistics()
                              let total = stat.TotalResults
                              let a = q.Statistics(&stat)
                              let rec addone n = seq { yield  q.Skip(n*1024).Take(1024).ToArray()
                                                       if n*1024 < total  then
                                                         yield! addone  (n + 1) }
                              addone 0 |> Array.concat
```

It works when you do

```
 let q =  session.Query<productypfield>()
 let r = q.getAll()
```

but breaks with

```
 let q =  session.Query<productypfield>().Where(System.Func ....)
 let r = q.getAll()
```

As the type Linq.IRavenQueryable is not idempotent through Linq composition : If I use Linq, I get an IEnumerable on which no q.Statistics(&stat) is defined.

I read the doc, and I dont see anyway to keep the type through Linq composition.
IS the only way to loop a fixed (high) amount of times, or set a high servepagesize, and take(a lot of elements) ?

**edit** : actually, even the code above does not work as apparently, to get a valid count, you need to run the query once. one has to call Take(0) to trigger it.

```
   use session = store.OpenSession()
   let q =  session.Query<productypfield>()
   let mutable s = Linq.RavenQueryStatistics()
   let a = q.Statistics(&s)  
   s.TotalResults = 0 //true
   printfn "%A" a      //triggers evaluation
   s.TotalResults = 0 //false
```

Comment: obviously I could define an index on the server, query through it, and just use my extension methods, but I feel I am missing something here

Comment: Be careful. Part of the "Safe By Default" includes a maximum number of queries per document session. I think that it is set to 30 by default.

Comment: yes I saw that part. this is not a problem as when I write, I know how many I write, and flush accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your 2nd code sample to this (I'm not familiar with F#):

```
let q =  session.Query<productypfield>().Where(Expression<System.Func<....>>)
let r = q.getAll()
```

that should let you keep the IQueryable that you need

Comment: but the IRavenQueryable property .Statistics(&stat) would still not be available I guess ?